# Calling nested function when function name is passed as a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a nested function by passing the function name in as a string and then calling it. Eg, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/javascript-function-name-as-a-string) post

```
function outer(action){
    window["outer"][action]();

    function inner(){
        alert("hello");
    }
}
outer("inner");
```

However it doesn't work. Error:

```
window.outer[action] is not a function
```

How to make this work, or an alternative way of calling a nested function.

The reason for this is that I am trying to hide a bunch of functions that are called by an iframe inside a functions scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function outer(action){
   var inner = {
     func1: function() {},
     func2: function() {},  
     func3: function() {},
     // ...
   }
   inner[action]();
}

outer("func1");
```

Answer (score 1):

In that way you are trying to access the "inner" property of the "outer" function (outer.inner) that is not defined. The only way to do that is by using eval:

```
function outer(action){
    eval(action+"()");

    function inner(){
        alert("hello");
    }
}
outer("inner");
```

But remember eval is evil is some situations so be careful.

Comment: eval. urgggh. galambalazs came up with a  solution.

Comment: You won't die if you use eval trust me:)

Comment: Yeah you won't die, Crockford won't kill you he'll just torture you till the end of time :P